# Checking every field in a "matrix" (with restriction)

Tags: haskell, recursion, matrix

i just learned haskell yesterday and i'm stuck with a task.
i have a Matrix given; implemented with a function like this:

```
board 1 1 = 0
board 1 2 = 1
board 1 3 = 0
board 2 1 = 2
board 2 2 = 0
board 2 3 = 0
board 3 1 = 1
board 3 2 = 0
board 3 3 = 2
board _ _ = -1
```

Just that you have a little context:
that matrix is used for a minified sinking ships game.
so you would check an entry 2 1  like this

```
board 2 1
```

and get the respective result.
0 is a default value, -1 doesnt exist; 1 stands for a ship owned by player 1, the same goes with 2.

Now i have to write a function that just has to count the amount of ships owned by a specific player  and it should return that amount.
e.g in that example board, the amount of 2's would be  2. 
However, i have a restriction that i cant use anything related to lists.
I guess i have to work with recursion, and this is where i'm stuck.

i already have made a try with this:
(k is the player number and res should be the result.)

```
amountofships k board = rekurs 1 1 board res
    where
    res = 0
    rekurs x y board res =
        if (board x y == -1) then return(res)
        else return(rekurs (x + 1) 1 board res)
        where
        new_rekurs a b board res2 =
            if (board a b == -1) then return(res2)
            else if (board a b == k) then return(new_rekurs a (b+1) board (res + 1))
            else return(new_rekurs a (b+1) board res)
            where
            res2 = 0
```

Its meant to have a resursion function that goes through every column and inside that, it has another recursion function that would check every entry inside that column, return the amount, then check the next column, etc.

it doesnt compile and i dont think its an elegant approach, but I cant think of another one.
I would be thankful for any kind of help.

**Edit :  Thank you all for your answers. I see where the problem in my Code was.**

I've used the structure proposed by Daniel, and it compiles at least:

```
amountofships k board = rekursColumn 1 1 0
  where
        rekursColumn x y res
            | board x y = res
            | otherwise = rekursColumn (x + 1) y (res + rowTotal)
            where
                rowTotal = rekursRow x y 0

        rekursRow x y res
            | board x y = res
            | otherwise = rekursRow x (y + 1) (res + isOurBoat)
            where
                isOurBoat = if board x y == k then 1 else 0
```

I still get an `Could not deduce (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘1’` 
Error when calling 
`amountofships 1 example_board`
. I guess this is because i didnt specify what the input types are? Specially since one parameter is actually a function.

**Edit2: Oh i see where the problem was. I need to check if `board x y == -1`
my Code is working now:**

```
amountofships :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int
amountofships k board = rekursColumn 1 1 0
  where
        rekursColumn x y res
            | board x y == -1 = res
            | otherwise = rekursColumn (x + 1) y (res + rowTotal)
            where
                rowTotal = rekursRow x y 0

        rekursRow x y res
            | board x y == -1 = res
            | otherwise = rekursRow x (y + 1) (res + isOurBoat)
            where
                isOurBoat = if board x y == k then 1 else 0
```

**Thank you all for your help!**

Comment: Could you explain "However, i have a restriction that i cant use anything related to lists". Is this a restriction of your course instructor, or are you working through some sort of self-study thing?

Comment: Yes, my course instructor made that task, so i'm kind of forced to use something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, yes, you're a bit confused.

So my advice first is to try to straighten out what you want to do, in mostly English. I'm going to try to lead you to that without outright giving you the answer, since the point of this exercise is for you to learn more Haskell.

So it seems to me - though you haven't explained it - that what you intend to happen is:

1. `amountofships` calls internal function `rekurs` telling it to start at position `1` `1` and passing it an accumulator argument that should start at `0`
2. `rekurs` should examine the spot it's given, and if that spot is `-1` say "oh, I'm off the grid, return the accumulator argument", and otherwise it should return the result of calling itself with one spot to the right.

Then you also somewhere define something called `new_rekurs` that you don't ever call.

So first let's try to fix your logic first, and then if you still have trouble translating that into Haskell we can work on that.

So the general pattern that you seem to be following is "call an internal tail-recursive function with an accumulator argument that checks "am I done yet?" and, if done, returns the accumulator argument. If not done, it computes the next place it should go and then calls itself on that."

Now, that's an okay pattern to use to solve this, but there are two problems with what you're doing:

1. You never add anything to the accumulator.
2. You need to travel in two dimensions.

So, traveling in two dimensions: there are two ways to do it. One is to keep a single function that keeps increasing `x` with each step until it gets to `-1` and then increases `y` by `1` and reset `x` to `1`. Another way - which I think in your case will be much, much easier - is to have two functions called `rekursBoard` and `rekursRow` (or whatever names you prefer) and the first function calls the second one to get the number of relevant ships in each row.

With the two-function solution, what you'd want to do is:

1. At the top level, call `rekursBoard 1 1 0` (the arguments there are `x`, `y`, and `res` - note that you don't need to keep passing the `board` function on down to the inner functions)
2. In `rekursBoard` check if the given spot is off the board. If it is, the result is just `res`. If not, then the result is `rekursBoard (x+1) y (res+rowTotal)`, where `rowTotal` is computed by calling `rekursRow x y 0`.
3. In `rekursRow`, check if the given spot is off the board. If it is, the result is just `res`. Otherwise, the result is `rekursRow x (y+1) (res+isOurBoat)`, where `isOurBoat` is computed as `1` if the boat at spot `x` and `y` matches the `k` the top-level function was given, and `0` if not.

The overall structure of your function could look like this:

```
amountofships k board = -- .... some call here
  where
    rekursBoard x y res = -- ... some stuff here
      where
        rowTotal = -- ... some call here
    rekursRow x y res = -- ... some stuff here
      where
        isOurBoat = -- ... something here
```

This isn't the only way to structure it, of course, it's just what I would do if I were writing up the answer sheet to this problem. Another very viable way to structure it is to make `rekursRow` something that's defined inside the `where` clause of `rekursBoard` and doesn't an `x` argument.

Now, a word in general on working in Haskell - Haskell has a function called `return` that means **almost nothing like you expect**. Seriously, at this early stage of learning Haskell, don't use `return` unless you're copying boilerplate code from the book. `return` DOES NOT DO WHAT YOU EXPECT. I personally think that the function is poorly named and that modern Haskell courses should avoid ever putting `return` on the page and instead use `pure` every place where they use `return`. (since on modern Haskell compilers, `return` and `pure` are the same thing for all the standard Monads)

Therefore, *if you put `return` in your Haskell code for this problem, you will be sorry*.

Don't do it.

Instead, get used to writing code like this:

```
countEmptySquare x y board = if board x y == 0 then 1 else 0
```

That is, just the form `if someExpression then onePossibility else otherPossibility`. No `return` statement, just bare expressions.

This will seem tedious at first, breaking down each calculation into named pieces, but it gets better. However, for laying out what's going on at an early level you should work through the careful break down.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand where the problem in my own code is(also thanks to the other answer i got).
 I've tried to implement your structure and it least compiles. (see my edited question above).

I still get an `Could not deduce (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘1’` error when calling it, may it be because i didnt set function signatures like function :: int -> int ?  however as i have a function as a parameter, how would i declare that correctly? 
`

Comment: That error means that you're using a `1` somewhere where Haskell thinks you should have a boolean (`True` or `False`) - one possibility is that you're doing somewhere something like "`if myfunction x y then ...`", where `myfunction` is something that returns a 0 or 1, and what you meant to write was "`if myfunction x y == 1 then ...`".

Comment: But as for your question about function signatures: yes, if you take a function as input, you write it like (Int -> Int). For example, your `amountofships` function could be declared as `amountofships :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int`, since the function `board` has type `board :: Int -> Int -> Int`

Comment: But yes, I agree with the advice in the other answer to write out function signatures in many spots when you're first learning Haskell. Writing out function signatures will help the compiler realize where you went wrong, and give you error messages close to the actual error - without function signatures, the compiler can sometimes infer very unexpected types while it's trying to make everything compile, and the end result is that you get an error far away from where you made the mistake.

Comment: `amountofships :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int` was also my first guess, now it complains that it  couldnt match the expected type bool with actual typ Integer.
The error message:
`• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: board x y
`, and i saw that its because i forgot to check if ` board xy ==  -1 `.  It works now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First let me clean up that code of yours, syntactically:

```
amountofships :: ... -- Always write out type signatures!
amountofships k board = rekurs 1 1 board res
 where res = 0
       rekurs x y board res
         | board x y == -1  = return res  -- guards usually read nicer than `if`
         | otherwise        = return $ rekurs (x + 1) 1 board res
        where new_rekurs a b board res2
                | board a b == -1  = return res2 -- no need for parens around function arguments!
                | board a b == k   = return $ new_rekurs a (b+1) board (res + 1)
                | otherwise        = return $ new_rekurs a (b+1) board res
               where res2 = 0
```

Now, a big problem here is `return`. Note that [`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Instances.html#v:return) in Haskell is very different from `return` in most other languages. It is *not* a keyword that's generally needed for the result of functions, instead, `return` is itself just a library function:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

You need this to inject a value of “pure type” `a`, for example `3 :: Int`, into the result of a *monadic action* of type `m a`, e.g. `Just 3 :: Maybe Int`. For example, you might use it thus:

```
-- Find the first even number in the tuple, if any
fstEven :: (Int, Int) -> Maybe Int
fstEven (a,b)
 | even a     = return a  -- for the `Maybe` monad, this is the
 | even b     = return b  --  same as writing `Just a` / `Just b`.
 | otherwise  = Nothing
```

Observe that I didn't write `return Nothing`: that would wrap the already monadic, *empty value* `Nothing :: Maybe Int` into another monadic layer, which is too much monad here.

Similar in your code: you wrap every result in `return`, but never unwrap anything.

Since in your case, everything is “pure” anyway, there's simply no need for that. To make something *the result of a function*, just write it out, like:

```
-- Use the first number in the tuple, if it's even; else use the second.
fstIfEven :: (Int, Int) -> Int
fstIfEven (a,b)
 | even a     = a
 | otherwise  = b
```

Or, in your case,

```
amountofships :: ... -- Always write out type signatures!
amountofships k board = rekurs 1 1 board res
 where res = 0
       rekurs x y board res
         | board x y == -1  = res
         | otherwise        = rekurs (x + 1) 1 board res
        where new_rekurs a b board res2
                | board a b == -1  = res2
                | board a b == k   = new_rekurs a (b+1) board (res + 1)
                | otherwise        = new_rekurs a (b+1) board res
               where res2 = 0
```

That looks better, but it doesn't work – here comes the interesting problem. See, you seem to not really think of *recursion* here. For a “recursive loop” in Haskell, you don't *initialise* a variable with something like `res = 0` and then somehow change it in the course of the loop. Rather you straight up *call the loop-body function* with the initial value as the “front-end argument”, and then keep the function calling itself with *other* arguments. I'll demonstrate it for the simplified problem with only one grid-dimension. Instead of these *magic numbers*, I shall use descriptive tag types:

```
data Player = PlayerA | PlayerB
 deriving (Eq, Show)

data BoardField = Coast | OpenSea | Ship Player
 deriving (Eq, Show)

type Board = Int -> BoardField   -- “array” of fields which may have ships in them, starting with index 0

amountOfShips :: Player -> Board -> Int
amountOfShips k board = go 0 0  -- the `board` is always the same, no need to pass
                                -- it explicitly to the worker-loop function `go`
 where go x res = case board x of  -- `case` is even better than guards, if all you're doing is equality comparison.
        Coast -> res             -- When we've reached the coast we're done, there can be no more ships.
        Ship player
          | player==k  -> go (x+1) (res+1)  -- Found ship of the requested player,
                                            -- therefore continue recursion with incremented accumulator
        _  -> go (x+1) res  -- No ships here, so continue recusion with the same accumulator.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I see know where the problem is :)
 I also didnt know that i shouldnt use return. And guards really do look better !
I've tried the structure proposed by Daniel's answer, see my edited question above :)